# How to prevent TransactionTooLarge exception while passing data between JobIntentService to activity via Broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, jobintentservice, transactiontoolargeexception

After login Page, I am downloading data from server using JobIntentService and passing the data to activity via BroadcastReceiver.
For smaller amount of data it works fine but when I am working on live data it is giving below exception:

```
Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 1450704 bytes
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:1127)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.broadcastIntent(IActivityManager.java:3893)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast(ContextImpl.java:1009)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast(ContextWrapper.java:444) 

I passing data like this from service class : 
Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_CHECK_DOWNLOADSTATUS);
intent.putExtra("response",response);
sendBroadcast(intent);


But it gives TransactionTooLargeException..
How to prevent this?

How do I pass large amount of Data ??

Pls suggest...
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass "large amount of data" in an `Intent`. If you have a "large amount of data" to pass then you need to use one of the following:

- Store the data in SQLite database
- Store the data in a file
- Store the data in a `public static` variable so that it can be accessed by all classes in your application (isn't the best alternative, as there are issues around app restarts, but it is the simplest method)